# Backup Exec runs out of tapes... because it hasn't scanned

Tags: backup, backupexec

Our particular tape drive inventories tapes based on barcode. Until it's done inventorying new tapes, it registers in BE as "Robotic door open" and we can't run a scan to update the tape inventory in BE.

We're a smaller shop and there's always something to get distracted by, which has led to backups failing a few times. BE thinks there's no tapes, but it never tries to scan the drive. Is there a way to enable "if you're out of tapes, make sure" or at least schedule a scan every day at a certain time or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following method in BE 12.5 and 2010 (and maybe earlier, I don't remember that far back): Shift-select all the slots in the library or drive, right click them, select Inventory, select the Schedule option in the left pane, select the "Run according to schedule" option, select a day\time prior to the beginning of your day's or week's backups, click the submit button. This will create a scheduled Inventory job, set to run on the day\time you scheduled.

If you swap tapes every day then schedule this for once a day, if you swap tapes once a week then schedule this for once a week, etc., etc.

For instance, we swap tapes once a week on Friday mornings. Our weekly backup cycle starts on Saturday mornings. I have this Inventory job scheduled to run every Friday night at 11PM.

Comment: Perfect! I wish I could schedule a scan instead of an inventory, but this will do just as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of version 10d at least, there was no way to schedule this. Because of this, we had to have "Scan barcodes" as part of our tape-change-day procedures. In our case, it would return the OLD bar-codes if the library hadn't gotten finished inventorying all the new tapes.

Comment: That's decidedly worse than "Close the barn door" that ours throws. Bummer!